# Can any one tell me what is wrong with PrepareStatement syntax

Tags: jdbc

```
public ResultSet readSubSet(int No, String name, String case) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT *  FROM target WHERE myName=? AND myCase=? LIMIT ?,10");
    preparedStatement.setString(8, name);
    preparedStatement.setString(6, case);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, No);
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();   
    return resultSet;
}
```

After run I got: `java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 2).`

my table define `myName` and `myCase` is `TEXT`, is that ok I use `prepareStatement.setString`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setString` you pass in two arguments, the first is the index of the parameter you are filling in and the second is the value you are filling it with. In your case, you would want `prepareStatement.setString(1,name);` to fill in the 1st parameter, `prepareStatement.setString(2,case);` to fill in the 2nd parameter, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL you only have 3 variables and you are setting variable 8 as name in preparedStatement.setString(8, name)...

Look @ http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps

Comment: Thank you very much. I am so silly, I thought that should be the index in my table.